# Compitability view mode, ie7-9

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have strange issue... i built aspx page (test.aspx) with the next head tag:

```
    <head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; " />
    <title>Just a test</title>
     </head>
```

and with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

at the start of the page.

I try to hide the button of the compitabillity... and i succses in other page (test2.aspx) (with the same code). the page is clear ! the body is clear...

The wierd thing is... i've checked the test.aspx on 4 friends computer... and ther is no compitabillity button - great !! i've also cheked that on my laptop and there is no button (ie8 and ie9)... but in my pc the button is display - why? i clear all the settings of my ie9 and the button is still there...

link:
http://bslide.co.il/test.aspx

I've click on the f12 button and i got the next error:

HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; ') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
test.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE Compatability mode has special rules if you're serving your page from `localhost`. And another set of rules if it's in your Intranet zone. You say, "friend's computer", "my laptop", and "my pc". Where is the page being opened from? Where are these machines (networkwise) relative to that server?

*My* PC doesn't show a compat mode button for that page.

Comment: Yep, but all what i wrote is about the link: www.bslide.co.il/test.aspx . maybe you have ie8/9 and you can tell me how that's look on you comuter? (the page is empty from content but offcurse i'm talking about the compi...buttn.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my laptop, where I am developing a new web site with Visual Studio 2010. I have also AVG Free 2011 installed, and I checked the source code of my page and I found these lines in the head tag, before any other tag:

```
<script src="/A2EB891D63C8/avg_ls_dom.js" type="text/javascript">
```

I saw this code in Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox 5, it was irritating.

That line of code breaks the Compatibility Button, because the meta tag of X-UA-Compatible should be the first line before any link or script tag, but after the title (as it says in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can read more of this issue in AVG in the following link:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/AVG-2011-Bug-Affects-Browsing-Experience-Could-Also-Hurt-Websites-160515.shtml

In short, if you have AVG installed, you should turn off the Surf-Shield component of AVG, and the problem should go away.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Jorge